# Password confirmation in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

This is my view:

```
<%=form_for [:admin, @user] do |f|%>

    <ul>
        <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>

    <%=f.label :name %>
    <%=f.text_field :name %>


    <%=f.label :email %>
    <%=f.text_field :email %>

    <%=f.label :password %>
    <%=f.password_field :password %>

    <%=f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%=f.password_field :password_confirmation%>

    <%=f.submit "Submit" %>
<%end%>
```

Controller code for adding user:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
        redirect_to admin_users_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

private
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password)
end
```

These are validations in the model:

```
validates :name, presence: true
validates :email, presence: true
validates :password, presence: true
validates :password, confirmation: { case_sensitive: true }
```

But `confirmation password` doesn't work.

Validation works for all  (they are required) form elements, except second password input - `password_confirmation` which can be different from first password input.

User is added to the database even if second password input is empty, because in the validation rules, there is no rule for that .

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: How do you declare strong params in the controller?

Comment: Hi, check the question again. I added code from my controller with params.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add `password_confirmation` to `user_params` in the controller.

I.e.

```
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Try: `validates_confirmation_of :password`

Model:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_confirmation_of :user_name, :password
  validates_confirmation_of :email_address, :message => "should match confirmation"
end
```

View:

```
<%= password_field "person", "password" %>
<%= password_field "person", "password_confirmation" %>
```

You could take a look to the [validates_confirmation_of](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_confirmation_of).

Comment: Same as before. I can add user without password confirmation.